# Passing data from form based on multiple fieldsets to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form which is based on multiple fieldsets . And I want to pass some of the values from each fieldset to my welcome.php. But the values aren't being displayed since nothing happens when I press submit. I am unable to figure out as to what is causing the problem. I am a beginner in PHP and any help would be highly appreciated. This my form code along with the jquery

```
<form id="msform"  action="welcome.php" method="post">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
         <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
        <li >Personal Details</li>
        <li>Social Profiles</li>

    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Account details</h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" id="f5"   required />
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" id="f6"  required />
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"  id="f1" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" title="someone@something.com" required />
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" id="f2" required />
        <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="f3" required />
        <input type="submit" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" id="v1"/>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
        <select name="country" required>
        <option value="">Select Your City</option>
        <option value="abt">Abbottabad</option>
        <option value="atk">Attock</option>
        <option value="bhp">Bahawalpur</option>
        <option value="chr">Charsadda</option>
        <option value="fsbd">Faisalabad</option>
        <option value="gujrat">Gujrat</option>
        <option value="guj">Gujranwala</option>
        <option value="hyd">Hyderabad</option>
        <option value="isb">Islamabad</option>
        <option value="khi">Karachi</option>
        <option value="lhr">Lahore</option>
        <option value="lark">Larkana</option>
        <option value="mnsh">Mansehra</option>
        <option value="mrdn">Mardan</option>
        <option value="mir">Mirpur Khas</option>
        <option value="mltn">Multan</option>
        <option value="nawab">Nawabshah</option>
        <option value="nwsh">Nowshera</option>
        <option value="psh">Peshawar</option>
        <option value="quet">Quetta</option>
        <option value="rwp">Rawalpindi</option>
        <option value="srg">Sargodha</option>
        <option value="skt">Sialkot</option>
        <option value="sheikh">Sheikhupura</option>
        <option value="sukr">Sukkur</option>
        <option value="tax">Taxilla</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" id="f7" pattern="[0][3][0-9]{9}"  title="Enter mobile number without country code" required />
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address" id="f8" required></textarea>
        <input type="number" name="cnicnum" placeholder="CNIC" id="f9" required/>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" id="v2"/>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Social Links</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Give a link to your social profiles (Optional)</h3>
        <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
        <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
        <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" id="v3" />
    </fieldset>

</form>

<script>

var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})

$('v1').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
alert('Validation was triggered!');
});

$('v2').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
alert('Validation was triggered!');
});

$('v3').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
alert('Validation was triggered!');
});
</script>
```

and this is my welcome.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
<body>

 <?php
 $name=$_POST['fname'];
 $lname=$_POST['lname'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $password=$_POST['pass'];
 $phone=$_POST['phone'];
 $cnic=$_POST['cnicnum'];
 $address=$_POST['address'];
 $twitter=$_POST['twitter'];
 echo ($name '<br>' $lname '<br>' $email '<br>' $password '<br>' $phone '<br>' $cnic '<br>' $address '<br>' $twitter '<br>');
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is var_dump($_POST); empty?

Comment: The echo call in welcome.php is wrong, , you should separate the variables and strings with commas e.g. `echo ($name, '<br>', $lname, '<br>', $email)`.
As you not reported error messages I suppose the error reporting are disabled in your server, so I recommend you to enable errors

Comment: I added the commas still nothing happened after submit.

Comment: The type of my submit button was button that is why it wasnt working. Changed it to submit and it worked

Answer (score 1):

From your code :

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
```

This means : "When I submit my form, don't do anything."

It's exactly what it does :)

By the way, are you aware that `$name=$_POST['fname']` is a terrible security flaw?

Comment: I removed all the jquery related to submit still the values dont get passed to welcome.php. And no I am not aware about it..

Comment: doing _POST['commonvalue'] is a terrible security flaw +1